# Unmarshal inconsistent JSON

Tags: json, serialization, go

I have JSON (that I cannot control) like this:

```
{
    "foo1":{
        "a":{
             "up":10,
             "down":5
        }
    },
    "foo2":{
        "a":{
             "up":1,
             "down":1
        }
    },
    "bar":{
        "up":11,
        "down":6
    }
}
```

"foo1" and "foo2" are dynamic.

How can I properly unmarshal this structure in go?

It would be okay if I could just tell go to not try to deserialize "bar" (the inconsistent property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I have JSON (that I cannot control)

So to what extent you could control? Here I could provide you with some scenario, and hope some of them match your purpose :)

Remember the general rule first:

**In Golang, if a JSON key failed to find a matched field in struct, it will not be unmarshalled.**

This means, for a key name in a JSON struct, when unmarshalling, it will look for a field in a golang struct at the same level with the same name case-insensitively. If this search failed, this key won't be unmarshalled.

For example, a key named `foo1` will look for a field name `foo1` in a golang struct at the same indent level. However it also matches with `Foo1` or `FoO1`, since this matching is case-insensitive.

Remember, you could use field tag to specify the field name as well. Please take a look at the [official page.](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)

#### The value of some of the JSON fields are not consistent, and they could be ignored.

This is the case @gnalck solved in his answer. According to the general rule, if those inconsistent field failed to find a match, they will not be unmarshalled. Therefore, just don't put those inconsistent fields in the struct and you will be fine.

#### The value of some of the JSON fields are not consistent, but they could not be ignored.

In this case, @gnalck failed since those fields could not be ignored. Now a better way is to unmarshal `bar` into a [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage), so that you could unmarshal later.

#### The keys of the JSON object is undetermined, and their value is undetermined as well.

In this case, we could unmarshal the whole JSON object into a `map[string]json.RawMessage`, and unmarshal each fields later. When unmarshalling to a map, you could iterate through the map to get all the fields, and unmarshal them into a proper struct later.

Comment: I ended up having to use RawMessage to deserialize "bar" separately. It seems this is the best way to do it for dynamic JSON like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go will by default ignore fields unspecified in the struct you unmarshal into.

In this case, your structure would be set up like this:

```
type NestedProp2 struct {
    Up   int
    Down int
}
type NestedProp struct {
    A NestedProp2
}
type Prop struct {
    Foo1 NestedProp
    Foo2 NestedProp
}
```

When you call the the json.Unmarshal function, the extra property will not be deserialized:

```
var prop Prop
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &prop)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", prop)
```

So you get the following output:

```
{Foo1:{A:{Up:10 Down:5}} Foo2:{A:{Up:1 Down:1}}}
```

You can see it in action [here.](https://play.golang.org/p/IHuOxMvXg2)

Comment: If the keys foo1,foo2,etc are dynamic, Prop can be declared as a map[string]NestedProp, so that you can access values using Prop[<key>].